# Github actions: How to view argo cd: kubernetes manifests, application and applicationset changes as in compact diff view of Argo CD GUI

Tags: github-actions, pull-request, git-commit, argocd

I would like to have manual Sync in my Argo CD cluster and I would like to have my CI pipeline using github workflow action where I will have a Pull Request proposing changes (let say increasing the number of repicas from 4 to 6) and my CI pipeline would would trigger a Workflow that will be react to PR and I need to add to the PR comment or create a new issue with a similar view of this Change like it is shown in Argo CD GUI - Compact diff and I need to know what files changed (in case multiple applicaton or applicationset are changed). I know I can grab the output of running argocd app diff argocd/webapp-kustom-prod
but I need to figure out what is changed in order to find what it the difference)

**So how to do this in a github workflow action.**

[image: Kubernetes manifests difference in Argo CD GUI]

[image: Argo CD CLI diff]

Answer (score 0):

There's an open-source project that does exactly this. See the [Infro Github Action](https://github.com/infro-io/infro-core?tab=readme-ov-file#as-a-github-action). Side note: I'm a maintainer.